# How to stay in fullscreen in web app when changing URL in iPadOS 13

Tags: html, ios, ipad, mobile-safari, progressive-web-apps

We have a web-application (web page) that the user saves to the homescreen and opens to show it full-screen on an iPad Pro.

As of iOS 13 (iPadOS 13), when we change the url of the page when a user taps a tab in the web page, a bar with "Done" and Aa shows, and it reverts back to the original page when done is pressed.

I've seen a lot of old posts about how to keep a home screen web app in full screen mode, but nothing seems to avoid the bar showing, and I wonder if something is broken for this in iOS 13.

Hs anybody experienced this and has a workaround?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide the new url bar on iPad Safari WebApp fullscreen mode, appearing since iPadOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393922/how-can-i-hide-the-new-url-bar-on-ipad-safari-webapp-fullscreen-mode-appearing)

Comment: have u find a solution? i have the same problem