# Is there a way to prevent the toolbar from appearing on route changes? IOS IPAD

Tags: ios, reactjs, ipad, safari, gulp

We have a web app that is added to the home screen of an iPad for a more "App like" user experience. It was working perfectly until the most recent iPadOS update which has been causing problems with the UI. Now when the user navigates, a minimal version of the safari toolbar appears [image: ipad issue]
I've since attempted to fix this issue by adding a manifest.json with the `display":"fullscreen",` property

```html
{
  "name": "1WSQ",
  "short_name": "1WSQ",
  "description": "1WSQ APP",
  "display": "fullscreen",
  "start_url": "/?homescreen=1",
  "background_color": "#000000",
  "theme_color": "#0f4a73",
  "icons": [
    {
      "src": "touch-icon-ipad-retina.png",
      "sizes": "256x256",
      "type": "image/png"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any other ideas on how this can be prevented would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I hide the new url bar on iPad Safari WebApp fullscreen mode, appearing since iPadOS 13?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393922/how-can-i-hide-the-new-url-bar-on-ipad-safari-webapp-fullscreen-mode-appearing)

Answer (score 0):

Try `"display": "standalone"` [manifest.json documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Manifest/display)

It's working for me on iPadOS 13.3

Comment: Turns out this question might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58393922/how-can-i-hide-the-new-url-bar-on-ipad-safari-webapp-fullscreen-mode-appearing/58507634#58507634